# Why does my search path content have so many backslash?

Tags: xcode, backslash, search-path

I have a project and I've found that the content in search path has many backslash at the beginning and the end of the correct search path.

It it like

```
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"$(SRCROOT)/MY-SEARCH-PATH"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

So is it a bug or something I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using some kind of tool (like Cocoa Pods or similar) on your project that modifies the project file. This tool might have a buggy way of interpreting build settings and saving them again.

Comment: Probably. But it happened before I started to use `CocoaPods` or some tool that I can remember.

Comment: @Gon Does it break again when you, for example `pod install` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

No idea, however it's wrong and should be changed back to:

```
$(SRCROOT)/MY-SEARCH-PATH
```

(i.e. no backslashes and no double-quotes)

Comment: That's true. I've corrected that and still searching why it happened.